# Sharepoint modal dialog from anotother dialog

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

When a user clicks on my button there appears a SharePoint modal dialog. The popup shows the user a confirmation message.  This is already working.

Now I want the following: When the users clicks on the YES button, the first popup closes and  and a new modal dialog opens.

Is this possible? And how? Or can i resize the dialog dynamicly when he's already open?

here are my methods to open the dialogs:

```
function OpenPopup() {
    var options = SP.UI.$create_DialogOptions();
    options.url = "popup.aspx";
    options.width = 230;
    options.height = 235;
    options.title = "";
    options.dialogReturnValueCallback = Function.createDelegate(null, CloseCallbackNew);
    SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
}

function OpenSecondPopup() {
    var options = SP.UI.$create_DialogOptions();
    options.url = "popup2.aspx";
    options.width = 630;
    options.height = 235;
    options.title = "";
    options.dialogReturnValueCallback = Function.createDelegate(null, CloseCallbackNew);
    SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it not as simple as

- Create a copy of your function `CloseCallbackNew` called `CloseCallbackNewSecond`
- Change `OpenSecondPopup` to reference this new copy instead of the original
- Add a call to `OpenSecondPopup` at the end of `CloseCallbackNew`, referencing the dialog result so as to only call it if the user clicked YES

It seems like this should call the second popup when the first is closed.